# Transparent lies meaning

Tags: meaning

After searching google for the meaning of **Transparent lies**, I could only find examples, but not the definition.

So, what does Transparent lies mean?

Comment: Give those examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should have googled **transparent**. :-)

[**transparent**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transparent): easily detected or seen through :  obvious

A **transparent lie** is a lie that is easily detected or seen through, an obvious lie.